# Dataframe - How to convert datetime to timestamp

Tags: pandas, dataframe

A column in dataframe keeps date like:

```
2019-06-19 23:04:36
2018-06-29 20:06:56
2019-03-04 11:12:35
2019-07-12 21:16:44
```

I tried the below code but it gives not correct results:

```
df['timestamps'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetimes']).astype('int64') / 10**9
```

The results are like these:

```
1.465506e+09
1.465516e+09
1.465503e+09
```

If I convert them again to date, I get incorrect date time:

```
df['new'] = df['timestamps'].apply(lambda x: pd.Timestamp(x))


1970-01-01 00:00:01.465506396
1970-01-01 00:00:01.465506397
1970-01-01 00:00:01.465506397
```

Something is not correct...

What is the way to convert date time that is as string like "2019-06-19 23:04:36" to timestamp?

Thank you.

Comment: You need to specify the `unit` while converting back to `Timestamp`. for example you could use `df['new'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamps'], unit='s')`

Comment: @ShubhamSharma Thank you. What you wrote is another way of getting it. But why the timestamps are like 1.465506e+09 and not simply as a number? Maybe the problem is also there.

Comment: you can get the number from `(pd.to_datetime(df['datetimes']).astype('int64') // 10**9)`, if you just divide it with `/10**9`, it will convert to `float` type, so it looks like `1.465506e+09`.